# Understanding memory management

Tags: ram, nodejs, memory-usage

I have an Ubuntu instance running a Node app. This is a web server application, so it is a long-running program that doesn't exit.

If I then run a Node script: `node ./something.js`, would this process use the exact same `node` memory image that was running the web server app?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Each process will have separate allocated memory.

Comment: So if Node requires 100MB, 200MB will be needed in my example? Aren't programs supposed to be re-entrant (pure) with multiple instances using a single code block with different data blocks?